# How do I get Facebook debugger to reference the correct og:image?

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

When I use the [Facebook debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/) to view my website top page, under the "Warnings That Should Be Fixed" section, I get a few different errors. However, if I press the "Fetch new scrape information" button one time, then on the next round only one error remains.

[image]

The error I am currently trying to solve is this one:

> *og:image could not be downloaded or is too small*
>
> og:image was not defined, could not be downloaded or was not big
>   enough. Please define
>   a chosen image using the og:image metatag, and use an image that's at
>   least 200x200px and is accessible from Facebook. Image
>   'http://davegutteridge.com/+image/mizumushi_profile.jpg' will be used
>   instead.

Facebook seems to have cached an old image and is displaying that one, even though I have deleted it from my server.

The image I want to show is [this one](http://davegutteridge.com/+image/davegutteridge2015comicprofilepic.jpg). To try and make it work, I've tried removing the "exif" data, I've tried making it square (my original was 1200 by 600 pixels), and I've ensured it's well above 200 by 200 pixels. I have also tried refreshing multiple times, and waiting over 24 hours to see if Facebook's cache changes. 48 hours after first discovering this problem, the debugger still shows the wrong image.

How do I get Facebook to reference the correct image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you follow the specificiations: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices#images

Square images are not a good choice, but i just tested it in the debugger and it does work fine. Btw, those are just warnings, not errors.

Comment: Thank you for responding. In this situation, though, it's more than just a warning. The image I have specified is not the image being selected for display. Also, as specified in the question, my original image was 1200 by 630, not square, but that didn't work either, and it was advice here on Stack Overflow that said to try a square image that was sized in increments of 100 pixels.

Comment: that was a very bad advice, i´m afraid. 1200x630 is definitely the best resolution.

Comment: Thank you for responding. I've replaced the image with [a version that is 1200x630](http://davegutteridge.com/+image/davegutteridge2015comicprofilepic.jpg), but the Facebook debugger still does not update and use the correct image.

Comment: one weird thing is that your og:url is this one: http://davegutteridge.com/dave_gutteridge - why not just http://davegutteridge.com? - anyway, another problem could be the + sign in the image url. although, it does show up good for me.

Comment: if it still does not work for you, you should file a bug: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/

Comment: Thank you for the link to the bug reporting. It looks like [many people are experiencing the same problem as I am](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/978421888869140/). I guess I will just have to wait for it to be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, where the image was set "correctly" but the debugger would not take it. So I played around, and figured out, that I could help the debugger by adding the `og:image:width` and `og:image:height`.
After that, the image was taken instantly :)
This Process is called pre-caching and here is the ref to it ;)
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices#precaching

Hope this helps!